# New Neo4J DB with indexes & constraints

Tags: neo4j

I am in the apparently minority case where I am starting my project from scratch rather than having data to import. I would like to have certain indexes and unique constraints applied to the nodes I will be creating. I see how these can be applied *after* nodes already exist. Is it possible to create these items *before* nodes exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It's exactly the same.

When you create a constraint, all existing nodes must be compliant for it to succeed (won't matter in your case) and all future nodes must be compliant for them to be created (this is your scenario).